# VB.NET don't get a successfull answer of a HTTP-Server

Tags: http, get, request, tcpclient, vb.net-2010

```
tcpClient.Connect("www.***.com", 80)

Dim message As String = "GET /***.html HTTP/1.1" & Chr(10) & "Host: www.***.com" & Chr(10)
tcpClient.Client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message))
```

I tried it with a few websites but it doesn't worked anywhere, I just become a error, that thers an timeout or the request is false and the server couldn't handle it. Here the code for the TcpClient:

```
Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient
```

Does anyone know whats wrong? I tried some combinations of the 'message' without Host and so on.